# cakephp not hashing password in model

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp 2 I have a form that creates a new record into the companies and users table.

My problem is that it saves into both table but in the Umuser table it does not hash the passwords or id key. It does not seem to call anything the the Umuser model at all. The is a before save and it does not call that.

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The Umuser is in the puging/Usermin/Models directory.

The company controller to save the data:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Company->create();

        if ($this->Company->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate'=>'first'))) {  // Should ensure both sets of model data get validated
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Cant see why it save the data but bypasses the Umuser model to do it.

Comment: Are those two models associated?

Comment: my tip: put this stuff in a centralized location to keep the code dry. a behavior is a great way of doing that on the model level: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: Yes the models are associated. The umuser table has a field called company_id. It does save the data, just not hash in the beforesave

Comment: I'm looking at the code and it's supposed to call `save()` for every model associated, when you call `saveAll` or `saveAssociated`. `save()` is supposed to call `beforeSave()`. Hm, weird behavior. They have a `hasOne` association then?

Answer (score 1):

$this->data[$this->alias]['password']) Probably someting wrong here.
Try to do something like this:

```
public function beforeSave() {
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    return true;
}else{
    return false; // if $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] is not set, don't save the model
}
```

}

then post here if the company has been saved